# Script Manager na MasterPage mas não funciona de forma correta

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Na página que estou alterando já existia um modal **modalOrgao**, e já estava sendo utilizado o `Script Manager` dentro da `Master Page`. Esse modal carrega um `gridview` com seus resultados, até ai tudo bem... Mas surgiu uma alteração e foi necessário chamar um novo modal (modalDetalhamento) com outro `gridview` (todos dentro de um UpdatePanel) Ai surge o problema!

**Como esse novo modal é chamado?**

Dentro de um `gridview` existe um botão que ao clicar carrega informações.
O modal é criado as informações são processadas, e antes que sejam apresentadas no modal, a página inteira faz o `postback` e consecutivamente o modal some e as informações não são apresentadas.
O **modalOrgao**, ele continua com seu funcionamento correto, não faz o `postback` na página e sim, somente, na área designada ao modal.

Não sei se passei corretamente as informações.

Desde já agradeço!

Segue um pedaço da minha **MasterPage**:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off" class="formValidation">
<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<uc1:barraTopo ID="barraTopo" runat="server" />
    <div id="container">
        <uc2:cabecalho ID="cabecalho" runat="server" />
            <div id="content">      
                <uc3:menu ID="menu" runat="server" />
                    <div id="main">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMensagem" runat="server" Text="Mensagem" CssClass="statusRealizado" Visible="false"></asp:Label> 

                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="contentPlaceHolder" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="contentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="contentPlaceHolder2" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                </div>

           <uc4:rodape ID="rodape" runat="server" />

     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Não é [tag:asp.net]?

Comment: Sim é asp.net.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mesmo configurando o novo UpdatePanel de detalhamento para ser disparador através de uma trigger de botão e no modo Conditional?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Estou dando esta alternativa mas recentemente tive um problema muito semelhante ao seu que não consegui resolver com UpdatePanel, acabei trazendo o resultado da consulta que eu queria usando AJAX + JQuery mesmo através de um WebMethod que retona os dados em JSON e jogando no meu novo modal. O resultado ficou muito bom e bem leve, como ja tinha perdido muito tempo com UpdatePanel decidi que foi a melhor solução. Foi algo parecido com isso aqui:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Relatorio.aspx/RetornaListaMedicoes',
    data: { ID: 1 },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        medicoes = JSON.parse(msg.d);
    }
});
```

E no code-behind um método:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string RetornaListaMedicoes(string ID)
{
}
```

Lembrando que o ScriptManager precisa estar habilitado para aceitar esse tipo de chamada:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
 </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Enfim, muitas vezes não conseguimos achar a solução técnica que precisavamos no começo mas é possível chegar ao mesmo resultado(ou até melhor) seguindo outro caminho. No me caso como a tela era complexa e o modal usava um componente javascript que eu não podia alterar facilmente, usar o AJAX para trazer os dados sem precisar do Postback salvou meu dia. :)

Abraços

Comment: Mesmo respondido após um certo tempo a resposta está correta! Fiz a mesma coisa que você sugeriu na época. Obrigado!